# ERROR: Exception when executing agent aggregation/aggregator( Execution Timeout Expired)

Tags: xconnect, experience-analytics, sitecore-install-framework, installation

I'm getting Execution Timeout Expired I tried below with no chance :

1. increase the time out on the connection string.
2. Set ping enabled to false.
3. Set the Ping Maximum Response Time (seconds) to a large value.

note : Experience analytics data is empty.
Do you know if there is any other setting I should apply to resolve this issue?

```
4264 13:44:18 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/aggregator
Exception: Sitecore.Xdb.Processing.Queue.ProcessingPoolException
Message: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Processing.Queue.SqlServer
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Processing.Queue.SqlServer.SqlServerProcessingPool`2.<OnCheckOutAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Processing.Queue.ProcessingPool`1.<CheckOutAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.AsyncPoolScheduler`2.<TryGetNextAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.InteractionAggregationAgent.<ExecuteCoreAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.Agent.<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.<ExecuteAgentAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.<RunAsync>d__26.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryCloseInternal(Boolean closeReader)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Close()
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Processing.Queue.SqlServer.SqlServerProcessingPool`2.<OnCheckOutAsync>d__41.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Message: The wait operation timed out
```

Comment: Try scaling up your instance to get rid of such an issue, follow this blog - https://sitecorejourney.nileshthakkar.in/2019/01/sitecore-error-exception-when-executing.html

Comment: @GauravAgarwal it's already scaled separate cm/cd

Comment: Any errors in the xConnect logs?

Comment: specifically, it's your DB and Processing Role that needs scaling. In this case, queries are timing out, which would most likely mean it's the DB that's running out of resources. If processing hasn't run in a while, it will  use a lot of resources

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same issue, my site is in Sitecore 10.0. Previously my application was working fine but the problem started as the certificate got renewed.
Make sure all three sites should have a proper license.

Below are the default `license` path details:

- For Identity Server, it's in the `\sitecoreruntime` folder.
- For xConnect site, it's in the `\App_Data` and subfolders of `App_Data\jobs\continuous`

[image]

and for the dev/public site, it is in `\App_Data`

Once all sites have proper `license` it worked for me.